# Unable to install Cassandra on Windows

Tags: windows, cassandra

Hey Guys I'm unable to install Cassandra on my PC. I'm getting an error like this

"cassandra : The term 'cassandra' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- cassandra
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cassandra:String) [], Command
  NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Suggestion [3,General]: The command cassandra was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\cassandra". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details."

I'm attaching all the screenshots, please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmEXr.png) let me know where I'm gone wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Windows support was completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)). There are several known issues with running Cassandra on Windows so support was limited even in earlier versions of Cassandra.

The recommended workarounds are:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using
  software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster
  with [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier and you can launch a cluster in 5 clicks. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As another possible method of achieving this, I recommend **running Cassandra on Minikube**.  I did a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMKXiItZ0Q4) on this recently, and have a [Git repository](https://github.com/aar0np/cassandra_minikube) full of scripts and steps to help folks get this running.

Here are the high-level steps (from the repo):

Download & install Minikube: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Clone my repo:

```
git clone git@github.com:aar0np/cassandra_minikube.git
```

Start Minikube, limiting it to 3GB and 2 CPUs:

```
minikube start --memory 3072 --cpus=2
```

Create a Kubernetes "service"

```
minikube kubectl -- apply -f cassandra-service.yaml
```

Create a Kubernetes "StatefulSet"

```
minikube kubectl -- apply -f cassandra-minikube_1node.yaml
```

Set up and run a port-forward

```
minikube kubectl -- port-forward service/cassandra 9042:9042
```